# How is the technique of calling function after function in the same line called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how this technique is called and if it's good practice. Also, what each function does?

```
$("div").first().parent().find(".projects").css("color","red").fadeOut(200);
```

Comment: Just look up each step in the [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). SO is not a code translation service.

Comment: Create a jQuery instance with all divs, create another instance with the first div in the element collection of jQuery instance, create another instance and put the parent element in, and do actions that affect this instance that affects their elements in collection (but not exactly what I'm saying)

Comment: You mean translated to vanilla JS???

Comment: Your code doesn't seem correct. $('div') selects the very first div on the page, not all like the answers below are suggesting.

Comment: @MollyHarper `$("div")` selects all the `div` elements not just the first!

Comment: @MollyHarper just so you'll stop saying that (because it's wrong) please see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/14/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("div")
  .first()
  .parent()
  .find(".projects")
  .css("color","red")
  .fadeOut(200);
```

This code uses chaining.

1. It finds all the divs within DOM
2. Of all the divs, it is taking the first div using `first`
3. Then get the parent of that div using `parent`
4. Then get all the `.projects` elements inside that parent using `find`
5. Then change the CSS of those elements using 'css'
6. Then hide those elements slowly (`200 ms`) using `fadeout`

It is using chaining here, which means it does not do the DOM search again and again, once it searches and then tries to apply all the methods on it.

Chaining means that each function will return a jQuery instance that contain all the search or filtering ... results so that you can call another function on that jQuery instance.

Chaining is a very good approach but it does take lot of time and slows down the application. [This reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240221/what-are-downside-and-advantage-of-method-chaining-in-jquery) from SO could be helpful.

Comment: Amazing explanation! Thank you.

Comment: I think _Chaining is a verry good.... and slows down the application_ is overkilling!

Comment: I would remove *Chaining is a very good approach but it does take lot of time and slows down the application* unless you want to back that up with some stats and an example...

Comment: This reference could be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240221/what-are-downside-and-advantage-of-method-chaining-in-jquery

Answer (score 4):

```
.first()
```

To find first element. [Exampe](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
.parent()
```

Used to select parent. [Example](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
.find()
```

Used to find element. [Example](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
.css()
```

Used to add `css`. [Example](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
.fadeOut()
```

Used to invisible element. [Example](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is good answer (with reference)!

Comment: "Used to invisible element.", lol  +1

Comment: The descriptions could be a little better. And you could include a little bit about how jQuery lets you chain methods.

Comment: Its not an English grammatical class :)

Comment: ...grammar class ;P

Answer (score 4):

This can be completely researched by you...

```
$("div")   // select div elements
  .first()  // get the first div element from all of the div elements from previous call
  .parent()  // get the parent element of the first div
  .find(".projects") // find the element with the class name "projects" within the div element
  .css("color","red") // change the color of that element to red
  .fadeOut(200); // hide that element by fading it to transparent with a duration of 200
```

---

**Documentation** (something I strongly suggest you look at):

[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

---

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is called chaining in jquery.

The code will behave like below.

```
$("div")  // select `div` elements from dom
  .first() // select the first `div` element from the list returned by previous call
  .parent() // it will select its first level parent
  .find(".projects") // find any inner element which has class `.project`
  .css("color","red")  // css will applied to the selected element
  .fadeOut(200);  // then it will fade out.
```

jquery implemented chaining in there library so that one function will work on another.

if you want to apply chaining in your own library, you need to return `this` so that another function will understand what you are returning.

Comment: Edited and upvoted

Comment: $("div") doesn't select all div elements from the dom, it selects the first that is found.

Comment: @MollyHarper no, it doesnt. It will in fact select all `div` tags

Comment: @MollyHarper, try it